# Java: collection that allows objects with a custom annotation

Tags: java, collections, annotations

I'd like to annotate some classes with a @MyEntity annotation

```
public @interface MyEntity {}

@MyEntity
public class MyClass { ... }
```

And define a collection where only classes with that annotation are allowed (with no need to define them as `public class MyClass implements XXX`):

```
List<MyEntity> list = new ArrayList<MyEntity>();
list.add(new MyClass())
```

The above code results in a complation error *"The method add(MyEntity) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (MyClass)"*.  Is there a way to define a collection that only allows objects with a given annotation?

Comment: You want the *precise* semantics of an interface when using annotations instead?  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Your problem is that `List<MyEntity>` defines a list of MyEntity's or its subclasses (i.e. if we have `@interface AnotherEntity extends MyEntity` then we could put `AnotherEntity` to this list).

Class `MyClass` doesn't extend/implement `MyEntity`, it's annotated with it.

Even if it was possible, it wouldn't be efficient. You wouldn't know which methods or fields are available, `MyEntity` doesn't describe your object's interface. So, the only thing it could be used for is filtering wrong insertions. You can implement it easily providing your List implementation:

```
List<?> myEntities = new LinkedList<?> {
   @Override 
   public boolean add(Object obj) {
       if (obj != null && obj.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyEntity.class)) {
           return super.add(obj);
       }
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only objects annotated with MyEntity are allowed");
   }

   @Override
   public boolean addAll(Collection<?> objs) {
      //something similar, maybe with Collections2.filter from Google Collections
   }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't think this is possible. Why not have them implement a no-method interface instead?

Answer (score 1):

The presence of an annotation doesn't modify the annotated class's type.

You could create a collection that only contains elements which are annotated with your annotation. You would need to make a wrapper class for the collection that uses reflection to check for the presence of the annotation on insertion.

It still won't get you compile-time type checking. For that you would need something which directly affects the insertable items' type (interface or superclass, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Just override methods of list: add, addAll and constructors, to filter classes that have expected annotation.